# Buttons not displaying on emulator while I can see them in design view

Tags: android

I am new in android development. I was trying to create some buttons but in android studio its showing in design view but when I run it on emulator it do not show any button there.

Sorry I was trying to post code before but it was not posting. now code is here. 
Please help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.sqatech.calculator.MainActivity"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button19"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="253dp"
    android:text="="
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="298dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="423dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button18"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:layout_marginStart="253dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="364dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="298dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button17"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="-"
    android:layout_marginStart="253dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="306dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="298dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="x"
    android:layout_marginStart="253dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="298dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="/"
    android:layout_marginStart="253dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="298dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button14"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="."
    android:layout_marginStart="191dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="423dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="211dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    android:text="1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="364dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_marginStart="117dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="364dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="3"
    android:layout_marginStart="191dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="364dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="210dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_width="173dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="423dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="348dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_marginStart="67dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="67dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="129dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="31dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="%"
    android:layout_marginStart="191dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="210dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="+/-"
    android:layout_marginStart="123dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="188dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="7"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="8"
    android:layout_marginStart="117dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="126dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="9"
    android:layout_marginStart="185dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="247dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="211dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="4"
    android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="305dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="5"
    android:layout_marginStart="123dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="306dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="123dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:text="6"
    android:layout_marginStart="185dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="305dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="210dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:text="AC"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="189dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="20dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with source code?

Comment: I am trying to post code here but its not posting.

Comment: Maybe you did something wrong. Please refer StackOverflow manual before posting any question/answers.

Comment: Post your XML code (activity_main.xml). Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: I have added the code in answer box.